# Which Firefox add-on checks if the latest plugins are installed?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

Is there a Firefox add-on that checks if I have the latest version of Adobe Flash, Sun Java, etc installed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although I did not find a plugin, Firefox has its own website to check this for you, known as ["Plugin Check and Updates"](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't aware that there was a web page I could do that although be ideal to have an add-on which checks every x period of time as opposed to visiting the web page every single time I want to validate if I have the latest updates.

Comment: I recommend putting it as a bookmark and periodically checking it.

Comment: Look who can vote to close now :p congrats!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Firefox itself can check if there are updates for the installed add-ons. This can be activated/deactivated in the sttings -> updates or in the add-ons-tab (hidden behind the "gear" icon).

Comment: Those are for addons, not plugins

Comment: However, knowing how to keep both updated is great.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up add-ons and plug-ins ...

Comment: It's still a solid answer! +1 for it. It's a good thing to realize the difference and see how to check both